# Actions on Google

Tags: actions-on-google

Is there any way to implement a music streaming service for Google Assistant using Action on Google? I have tried SSML simple responses but the limitation is 120 seconds. I would like to play a continuous stream. Google has a streaming service called Podcasts that works with Google Assistant but I cannot find any references in the developer docs to address such applications.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No streaming support on Actions on Google yet, but it's coming.

Answer (score 1):

Google just released information on creating a [Podcast Action](https://developers.google.com/actions/content-actions/podcasts).

In short - you need to have a page that will be found by Google's bot that contains correctly formatted information about a valid RSS2 feed containing the podcast info. From there, it should be picked up and made available in Google's index.

Comment: Thanks. This is workable but in a very indirect manner. I guess we have to live with that until a more direct way is made available where you don't have to setup an RSS feed to achieve your end goal. At least something is better than nothing.

Comment: Well, for something that is a podcast - what are you looking for? (For something more interactive - yeah... we're still waiting for a way to do streaming.)

Comment: Not want to deliver a podcast experience. Instead a personal music player like service with basic player controls like pause, next/previous plus allow users to create their own playlists, share playlists with each other. Offer weekly playlists from service etc.

Comment: Ok, that wasn't clear from your OP. As noted, that sort of feature isn't available, but one can safely assume they're working on it.